# Create Android Library on Flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, android-library

I am trying to create an android library on top of flutter project for distribution. I have developed an app using flutter, but I want to wrap it in an Android library.  I keep getting error `Transform output file /Users/Dev/Documents/projects/LibExample/testlib/build/intermediates/flutter/flutter-x86.jar does not exist.` I have read search almost everything online, but nothing so far.

The `LibExample` is my sample app to use the library while `testlib` is the Android library. In the `testlib` I have set up my `build.graddle` to locate the `flutter.sdk`. I have also specified the flutter source location. Each time I `sync` the gradle file, I get the error /Users/Dev/Documents/projects/LibExample/testlib/build/intermediates/flutter/flutter-x86.jar does not exist.
`

Here is the output for `flutter doctor -v`.

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.2-pre.1, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.5.2-pre.1 at /Users/Dev/Downloads/flutter
    • Framework revision 142e2f41ba (9 weeks ago), 2018-09-03 12:50:53 +0100
    • Engine revision 1ed25ca7b7
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.58.0.flutter-f981f09760

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/Dev/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 10.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.1, Build version 10B61
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 29.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[!] VS Code (version 1.28.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • Android SDK built for x86 • emulator-5554 • android-x86 • Android 5.1.1 (API 22) (emulator)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11958 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14821

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I finally stumble on this feature on one of flutter wiki [page](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Add-Flutter-to-existing-apps). 
A very important thing to note as of this write-up;

The "add2app" support is in preview, and is so far only available on the master channel.

Although this feature is still experimental but it works fine (few snags tho, like the time it takes to launch the flutter app when you call in from the Android host).

Flutter projects created using `flutter create xxx` include very simple host apps for your Flutter/Dart code (a single-Activity Android host and a single-ViewController iOS host). You can modify these host apps to suit your needs and build from there.

But if you're starting off with an existing host app for either platform, you'll likely want to include your Flutter project in that app as some form of library instead.

This is what the Flutter module template provides. Executing `flutter create -t module xxx` produces a Flutter project containing an Android library and a Cocoapods pod designed for consumption by your existing host app.

**Android**

Create a Flutter module
Let's assume you have an existing Android app at some/path/MyApp, and that you want your Flutter project as a sibling:

```
$ cd some/path/
$ flutter create -t module my_flutter
```

This creates a `some/path/my_flutter/` Flutter module project with some Dart code to get you started and a `.android/` hidden subfolder that wraps up the module project in an Android library.

(While not required in what follows, if you so desire, you can build that library using Gradle:

```
$ cd .android/
$ ./gradlew flutter:assembleDebug
```

This results in a `flutter-debug.aar` archive file in `.android/Flutter/build/outputs/aar/.`

**Make the host app depend on the Flutter module**

Include the Flutter module as a sub-project in the host app's `settings.gradle`:

```
// MyApp/settings.gradle
include ':app'                                     // assumed existing content
setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))                                 // new
evaluate(new File(                                                      // new
  settingsDir.parentFile,                                               // new
  'my_flutter/.android/include_flutter.groovy'                          // new
))                                                                      // new
```

The binding and script evaluation allows the Flutter module to `include` itself (as `:flutter`) and any Flutter plugins used by the module (as `:package_info`, `:video_player`, etc) in the evaluation context of your `settings.gradle`.

Introduce an `implementation` dependency on the Flutter module from your app:

```
// MyApp/app/build.gradle
:
dependencies {
  implementation project(':flutter')
  :
}
```

**Use the Flutter module from your Java code**

Use the Flutter module's Java API to add Flutter views to your host app. This can be done by directly using `Flutter.createView`:

```
// MyApp/app/src/main/java/some/package/MainActivity.java
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    View flutterView = Flutter.createView(
      MainActivity.this,
      getLifecycle(),
      "route1"
    );
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams layout = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(600, 800);
    layout.leftMargin = 100;
    layout.topMargin = 200;
    addContentView(flutterView, layout);
  }
});
```

It is also possible to create a `FlutterFragment` that takes care of lifecycle by itself:

```
// MyApp/app/src/main/java/some/package/SomeActivity.java
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    FragmentTransaction tx = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    tx.replace(R.id.someContainer, Flutter.createFragment("route1"));
    tx.commit();
  }
});
```

Above we use the string `"route1"` to tell the Dart code which widget to display in the Flutter view. The `lib/main.dart` file of the Flutter module project template should `switch` on (or otherwise interpret) the provided route string, available as `window.defaultRouteName`, to determine which widget to create and pass to `runApp`. Schematically,

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(_widgetForRoute(window.defaultRouteName));

Widget _widgetForRoute(String route) {
  switch (route) {
    case 'route1':
      return SomeWidget(...);
    case 'route2':
      return SomeOtherWidget(...);
    default:
      return Center(
        child: Text('Unknown route: $route', textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
      );
  }
}
```

It is entirely up to you which route strings you want and how to interpret them.

**Building and running your app**

You build and run `MyApp` in exactly the same way that you did before you added the Flutter module dependency, typically using Android Studio. The same goes for editing, debugging, and profiling your Android code.

**Hot restart/reload and debugging Dart code**

Full IDE integration to support working with the Flutter/Dart code of your hybrid app is work in progress. But the fundamentals are already present via the Flutter command line tools and the Dart Observatory web user interface.

Connect a device or launch an emulator. Then make Flutter CLI tooling listen for your app to come up:

```
$ cd some/path/my_flutter
$ flutter attach
```

Waiting for a connection from Flutter on Nexus 5X...
Launch `MyApp` in debug mode from Android Studio (or whichever way you usually do it). Navigate to an area of the app that uses Flutter. Then turn back to the terminal, and you should see output similar to the following:

```
Done.
Syncing files to device Nexus 5X...                          5.1s

  To hot reload changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and rebuild state), press "R".
An Observatory debugger and profiler on Nexus 5X is available at: http://127.0.0.1:59556/
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".
```

You can now edit the Dart code in `my_flutter`, and the changes can be hot reloaded by pressing `r` in the terminal. You can also paste the URL above into your browser to use the Dart Observatory for setting breakpoints, analyzing memory retention and other debugging tasks.

**iOS**
**Create a Flutter module**

Let's assume you have an existing iOS app at `some/path/MyApp`, and that you want your Flutter project as a sibling:

```
$ cd some/path/
$ flutter create -t module my_flutter
```

This creates a `some/path/my_flutter/` Flutter module project with some Dart code to get you started and a `.ios/` hidden subfolder that wraps up the module project that contains some Cocoapods and a helper Ruby script.

**Make the host app depend on the Flutter module**

The description below assumes that your existing iOS app has a structure similar to what you get by asking Xcode version 10.0 to generate a new "Single View App" project using Objective-C. If your existing app has a different folder structure and/or existing `.xcconfig` files, you can reuse those, but probably need to adjust some of the relative paths mentioned below accordingly.

The assumed folder structure is as follows:

```
some/path/
  my_flutter/
    lib/main.dart
    .ios/
  MyApp/
    MyApp/
      AppDelegate.h
      AppDelegate.m (or swift)
      :
```

**Add your Flutter app to your Podfile**

Integrating the Flutter framework requires use of the CocoaPods dependency manager. This is because the Flutter framework needs to be available also to any Flutter plugins that you might include in my_flutter.

Please refer to [cocoapods.org](https://cocoapods.org/) for how to install CocoaPods on your development machine, if needed.

If your host application (`MyApp`) is already using Cocoapods, you only have to do the following to integrate with your `my_flutter` app:

Add the following lines to your `Podfile`:

```
flutter_application_path = 'path/to/flutter_app/'
  eval(File.read(File.join(flutter_application_path, '.ios', 'Flutter', 'podhelper.rb')), binding)
```

Run `pod install`.

Whenever you change the Flutter plugin dependencies in `some/path/my_flutter/pubspec.yaml`, you need to run flutter packages get from `some/path/my_flutter` to refresh the list of plugins read by the `podhelper.rb` script. Then run pod install again from `some/path/MyApp`.

The podhelper.rb script will ensure that your plugins and the Flutter.framework get added to your project, and also ensure that bitcode is disabled for all targets.

**Add a build phase for building the Dart code**

Select the top-level `MyApp` project in the Project navigator. Select **TARGET** `MyApp` in the left part of the main view, and then select the `Build Phases` tab. Add a new build phase by clicking the `+` towards the top left of the main view. Select `New Run Script` Phase. Expand the new `Run Script`, just appended to the list of phases.

Paste the following into the text area just below the Shell field:

```
"$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build
"$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" embed
```

Finally, drag the new build phase to just after the Target Dependencies phase.

You should now be able to build the project using `⌘B`.

Under the hood
If you have some reason to do this manually or debug why these steps aren't working, here's what's going on under the hood:

1. `Flutter.framework` (the Engine library) is getting embedded into your
   app for you. This has to match up with the release type
   (debug/profile/release) as well as the architecture for your app
   (arm*, i386, x86_64, etc.). Cocoapods pulls this in as a vendored
   framework and makes sure it gets embedded into your native app.
2. `App.framework` (your Flutter application binary) is embedded into
   your app.
3. `flutter_assets` folder is getting embedded as a resource - it
   contains fonts, images, and in certain build modes it also contains
   binary files required by the engine at runtime. **Problems with this
   folder can lead to runtime errors such as "Could not run engine for
   configuration" - usually indicating that either the folder is not
   getting embedded, or you're trying to cross a JIT application with
   an AOT enabled engine, or vice versa!**
4. Any plugins are getting added as Cocoapods. In theory, it should be
   possible to manually merge those in as well, but that becomes much
   more specific to the plugin itself.
5. Bitcode is disabled for every target in your project. This is a
   requirement to link with the Flutter Engine.
6. Generated.xcconfig (containing Flutter-specific environment
   varaibles) is included in the release and debug .xcconfig files that
   Cocoapods generates.

The build phase script (xcode_backend.sh) is ensuring that the binaries you build stay up to date with the Dart code that's actually in the folder. It also attempts to respect your build configuration setting once [this pull request](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/23387) lands (which already did!).

Write code to use FlutterViewController from your host app
The proper place to do this will be specific to your host app. Here is an example that makes sense for the blank screen of the host app generated by Xcode 10.0.

First declare your app delegate to be a subclass of `FlutterAppDelegate`.

In `AppDelegate.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>

@interface AppDelegate : FlutterAppDelegate
@end
```

This allows `AppDelegate.m` to be really simple, unless your host app needs to override other methods here:

```
#import <FlutterPluginRegistrant/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.h> // Only if you have Flutter Plugins

#include "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

// This override can be omitted if you do not have any Flutter Plugins.
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  [GeneratedPluginRegistrant registerWithRegistry:self];
  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

@end
```

If you are writing in Swift, you can do the following in your `AppDelegate.swift:`

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import FlutterPluginRegistrant // Only if you have Flutter Plugins.

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {

  // Only if you have Flutter plugins.
  override func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self);
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions);
  }

}
```

.......

```
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button addTarget:self
               action:@selector(handleButtonAction)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"Press me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)handleButtonAction {
    FlutterViewController* flutterViewController = [[FlutterViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentViewController:flutterViewController animated:false completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Or, using Swift:

```
ViewController.swift:

import UIKit
import Flutter

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let button = UIButton(type:UIButtonType.custom)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.setTitle("Press me", for: UIControlState.normal)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 80.0, y: 210.0, width: 160.0, height: 40.0)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    self.view.addSubview(button)
  }

  @objc func handleButtonAction() {
    let flutterViewController = FlutterViewController()
    self.present(flutterViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

You should now be able to build and launch MyApp on the Simulator or on a device. Pressing the button should bring up a full-screen Flutter view with the standard Flutter Demo counting app. You can use routes to show different widgets at different places in your app, as described in the Android section above. To set the route, call

Objective-C:

```
[flutterViewController setInitialRoute:@"route1"];
```

Swift:

```
flutterViewController.setInitialRoute("route1")
```

immediately after construction of the `FlutterViewController` (and before presenting it).

You can have the Flutter app dismiss itself by calling `SystemNavigator.pop()` in the Dart code.

**Building and running your app**

You build and run MyApp using Xcode in exactly the same way that you did before you added the Flutter module dependency. The same goes for editing, debugging, and profiling your iOS code.

**Hot restart/reload and debugging Dart code**

Connect a device or launch a Simulator. Then make Flutter CLI tooling listen for your app to come up:

```
$ cd some/path/my_flutter
$ flutter attach
Waiting for a connection from Flutter on iPhone X...
```

Launch `MyApp` in debug mode from Xcode. Navigate to an area of the app that uses Flutter. Then turn back to the terminal, and you should see output similar to the following:

```
Done.
Syncing files to device iPhone X...                          4.7s

  To hot reload changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and rebuild state), press "R".
An Observatory debugger and profiler on iPhone X is available at: http://127.0.0.1:54741/
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".
```

You can now edit the Dart code in `my_flutter`, and the changes can be hot reloaded by pressing `r` in the terminal. You can also paste the URL above into your browser to use the Dart Observatory for setting breakpoints, analyzing memory retention and other debugging tasks.

**Debugging specific instances of Flutter**

It's possible to add multiple instances of Flutter (`root isolates`) to an app. `flutter attach` connects to all of the available isolates by default. Any commands sent from the attached CLI are then forwarded to each of the attached isolates.

List all attached isolates by typing `l` from an attached `flutter` CLI tool. If unspecified, isolate names are automatically generated from the dart entry point file and function name.

Example `l` output for an application that's displaying two Flutter isolates simultaneously:

```
Connected views:
  main.dart$main-517591213 (isolates/517591213)
  main.dart$main-332962855 (isolates/332962855)
```

1. Attach to specific isolates instead in two steps:

Name the Flutter root isolate of interest in its Dart source.

```
// main.dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

void main() {
  ui.window.setIsolateDebugName("debug isolate");
  // ...
}
```

1. Run `flutter attach` with the `--isolate-filter` option.

`$ flutter attach --isolate-filter='debug'`

```
Waiting for a connection from Flutter...
Done.
Syncing files to device...      1.1s

  To hot reload changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and rebuild state), press "R".
An Observatory debugger and profiler is available at: http://127.0.0.1:43343/
For a more detailed help message, press "h". To detach, press "d"; to quit, press "q".

Connected view:
  debug isolate (isolates/642101161)
```

Another feature still in experimental I found that may interest you is [Obfuscating dart code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/23387)

Comment: while it is fine to link to external pages you should always post the actual answer/explanation directly on SO. The reason is that when external site goes away, your answer is still useful for others. In current situation, you answer is useless unless you visit external site to figure out what it all about. Please fix that

Comment: Hi mate, can you please help me how to add existing flutter app to Android (Manual). Your guide is create a new module in an Android app